# When I open the modal, the api call running always

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like that if I click onto a link and the modal is open the api call runs one time.
Unfortunately it's running always, till the open state is true.

```
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [content, setContent] = useState();

    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);


    const fetchData = async (movieName) => {
    console.log("Fetching");
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&origin=*&list=search&utf8=1&formatversion=latest&srsearch="${movieName}" articletopic:films`
    );

    setContent(data);
    console.log(data);
  };

    if (open) {
    fetchData();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `useEffect` hook to call the API only once when the component is mounted.

Replace below

```
 if (open) {
    fetchData();
 }
```

with

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
...
...
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are directly calling `fetchData` when `open` is true. When api call is successful it `setContent`. Which triggers component to re render. It agains call the api and sets state re-render and so on. Call api inside `useEffect`.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (open) {
            fetchData();
        }
    }, [open]);
```